# Raw cream safe to consume after 125 F for 12 hours?

Tags: cream, dairy, raw

I was attempting to make clotted cream with pure raw cream (jersey cows) from the dairy farm.

I had my temperature too low I think though. **I had it "cooking" at 125 F for 12 hours.** It should have been 160 F for 12 hours.

Can I increase the temperature and cook for additional time?

*Some websites say temperatures as low as 110 F will work for clotted cream.*

https://www.english-cottage-lifestyle.com/English_Cottage_Lifestyle-clotted-cream.html

Comment: Welcome! You are asking two questions - is it safe (no) and can I heat it to make it safe (also no). But please note that food safety will simply say whether something is safe, not whether it’s actually spoiled. It’s up to you to decide, which risks you are willing to take.

Comment: Thank you very much. I remade at the safe temp with a fresh batch of raw cream and it smells great.